# "Nur" im Sinn von Entschuldigung

Tags: word-usage

Ich habe bemerkt, dass es in der englischen Sprache üblich ist, das Wort "only" zu benutzen, um jemanden oder sich selbst zu entschuldigen. Zum Beispiel,

"What took you so long?"

"I was only checking to make sure the doors were locked."

Meine Frage ist: darf man das deutsche Wort "nur" in einem ähnlichen Kontext benutzen?

"Warum hast du so lange gebraucht?"

"Ich habe nur geprüft, ob die Türe versperrt waren."

Vielen Dank für Eure Hilfe

Comment: Ich möchte noch einen Aspekt hinzufügen. Dieses Wort wird nicht nur entschuldigend verwendet, sondern ganz allgemein auch für eine Rechtfertigung, ob diese nun erwartet wird oder nicht, ja manchmal ist nicht einmal klar ist, wofür eine Person sich rechtfertigt. Ein Phänomen, das heute recht verbreitet ist - wollte ich _nur_ mal so hinzufügen!

Comment: Ich kann absolut nicht erkennen, wie man _nun_ im Sinne einer Entschuldigung verstehen könnte. In den Beispielen kommt _nun_ mit seiner üblichen Bedeutung "nicht mehr als" zufällig im Kontext einer Entschuldigung vor; aber das gilt auch für alle anderen Worte, wie beispielsweise _ich_ und _habe_. Trotzdem würde man nicht auf die Idee kommen, dass _ich_ und _habe_ hier eine spezielle Bedeutung im Sinne einer Entschuldigung hätten. Das gilt übrigens im Deutschen wie in jeder anderen Sprache.

Comment: @AshwinSchumann Interessant, danke für die Bemerkung. Es gibt ja vieles zu deuten in diesem kleinen Wort.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ja. Diese Formulierung ist auch im Deutschen absolut üblich.

> "Was machst du hier?" - "Ich wollte nur nach den Blumen sehen."

Comment: A synonymous word which is also often used in this sense is "bloß": "Ich wollte bloß nach den Blumen sehen."